# For which angle $x$, it results $0 < \cos(x) < \sin(x)<1$?

Tags: trigonometry

For which angle $x$, it results $0 < \cos(x) < \sin(x) < 1$?

1. 40°
2. 50°
3. 60°
4. 70°
5. 80°

Why is the correct answer #3 60° and not #3,4,5?

Yet, if the question asks: For which angle X, it results $0.5 < \cos(x) < \sin(x) < 1$?, the answer is #2 50°

Comment: The correct answer is option $2$ as well.

Comment: Given that every answer *except* $40^\circ$ is valid, I wonder if the question was mis-stated.

Comment: @Blue Thanks for your feedback, I copied the question directly from an entrance exam to a prestigious university in Europe. I'm new, so I'm not able to upvote your useful comment.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine constructing a *right* triangle as follows:

One point is the point $A$ at $(0,0)$.

One point is the point $B$ at $(x,0)$.

One point is the point $C$ at $(x,y)$ subject to the following two constraints:

1. The point $(x,y)$ is a point on the unit circle, so you have that $x^2 + y^2 = 1.$
2. $0^{\circ} < \angle BAC < 90^\circ.$

Note that the $\cos(\angle BAC) = x$ and the $\sin(\angle BAC) = y$.  This is because the right triangle was intentionally constructed so that its hypotenuse has a length of $1$.

Therefore, the question of the comparison of the cosine of $\angle BAC$ versus the sine of $\angle BAC$ **reduces** to comparison of the values for the corresponding numbers $x$ and $y$.

When $\angle BAC = 45^{\circ}$, you have that the **slope** of the line segment $(x,y) -- (0,0)$ is equal to $1$, so when $\angle BAC = 45^{\circ}$, $y$ exactly equals $x$.

When $0^{\circ} < \angle BAC < 45^\circ,$ the slope of the line segment $(x,y) -- (0,0)$ is less than $1$, which implies that $y < x.$

When $45^{\circ} < \angle BAC < 90^\circ,$ the slope of the line segment $(x,y) -- (0,0)$ is greater than $1$, which implies that $y > x.$

Answer (score 0):

Let us start with some considerations.

To begin with, we shall emphasize that $0 < \cos(x) < 1$ and $0 < \sin(x) < 1$ iff $x\in(0,\pi/2)$.

The $\cos$ function is strictly decreasing on $(0,\pi/2)$ and the $\sin$ function is strictly increasing on $(0,\pi/2)$

Once $\cos(\pi/4) = \sin(\pi/4)$, if we take $x\in(0,\pi/4)$, then $\sin(x) < \sin(\pi/4) = \cos(\pi/4) < \cos(x)$.

On the other hand, if we take $x\in(\pi/4,\pi/2)$, then $\cos(x) < \cos(\pi/4) = \sin(\pi/4) < \sin(x)$.

So any angle $x$ which belongs to $(\pi/4,\pi/2)$ satisfies the proposed relation.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Probably best to present this answer using degrees, as the mathematical level of question being asked here makes it likely that OP has not yet been introduced to radians. Also worth pointing out that this does not completely answer the question, as it really requires a few words on the answers given in the multiple choice question which OP is trying to make head or tail of.

Comment: @PrimeMover Thanks! I'm new, so I'm not able to upvote your useful comment.